# Improve performance of IE driver in Selenium1

Tags: jquery, performance, selenium

I recently experienced that Selenium1 works very good with Firefox using XPath but
its very very slow with IE.
Is there any solution to increase performance in IE of Selenium1 ?

I've found out that people use JQuery element-locators in Selenium. 
I like the idea and I'd like to ask about pros & cons of using JQuery selectors instead of XPath ones. 
Are they more "flexible" or fast, let's say in IE ?

Actually Problem is with IE only while using Selenium1, So I am thinking to use JQuery locators instead of XPath but i dont know whether using JQuery locator would be as easy to use as XPath ?

Is there any plugin by which I can get JQuery locator like XPather ? 
Is there any way to convert existing XPath into JQuery locator ?

Because i have around thounsands of test already implemented & running fine with Firefox Selenium1 now need to make all of them running fine with IE Selenium1. I am desperately looking for solution.

Any suggestion for issue.
I am desperately looking for solution.

Thank you.

Comment: "Pros & cons" without complete use case are very much subjective.

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks for your comment, Actually Problem is with IE only while using Selenium1, So I am thinking to use JQuery locators instead of XPath but i dont know whether using JQuery locator would be as easy to use as XPath ?  Is there any plugin by which I can get JQuery locator like XPather ?   Is there any way to convert existing XPath into JQuery locator ?  Because i have around thounsands of test already implemented & running fine with Firefox Selenium1 now need to make all of them running fine with IE Selenium1. I am desperately looking for solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not faster, xpath is generally more flexible, but if you already have the JQuery selectors written in your JavaScript then you might as well use them in your tests as it saves you having to write the extra selector.

Selenium is slow in IE because the JavaScript engine in IE is unbelievably bad, on my last project I had a build that took about an hour to run in Firefox (faster in Chrome) but took over 6 hours in IE.

You may also like to look at [best way to detect an element on a web page for seleniumRC in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5313847/569659)

Comment: Thank for reply. I tried Selenium2 to solve performance issue but with that some other new issues comes up (like PopUp handling, Bind exception etc.) as Selenium2 is still in beta version. 

So I looking for some smart solution with Selenium1 for IE,
Is there any firefox-plugin like XPather for JQuery selector/locator ?  As it would be easy to get JQuery locator.

Comment: @SmartSolution if you use firebug the javascript console will allow you to execute javascript snippets. This will let you evaluate `$jQuery()` and as such you can test your selectors. But I would encourage the use of XPath over css selectors.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why are you encouraging use of XPath over JQuery/CSS selector even though XPath manipulation is too slow in IE ?

Comment: As @Ardesco said above, IEs support of CSS selectors is shaky.

Answer (score 1):

You could try one of the other XPath implementations built in.  By default the following is set:

```
selenium.useXpathLibrary("ajaxslt");
```

try switching to:

```
selenium.useXpathLibrary("javascript-xpath");
```

This should be a bit faster.

Comment: I already tried this but still speed is not improved to satisfactory level :(

Comment: This is due to IE's JavaScript rendering engine(which is dire and horrifically slow), I think you will find that once you have gone to all the hassle of trying to insert jQuery into the page and writing a jQuery framework to enable you to use it as a locator strategy you will still have the same problems.

The issue is not XPath, it is IE and the fact that it does not nativly support XPath in the older versions so it emulates XPath locators using a JavaScript implementation.

Comment: For speed in IE in Selenium 1 you will have to use CSS locators, but you then may have issues with CSS support in old versions of IE (If I remember correctly not all of CSS2 is supported and no CSS3 which makes CSS as a locator strategy a real pain).  You also have to deal with IE not utilising CSS in the same way as other browsers meaning different locators for IE in some circumstances.

Basically IE is a pain in the a** to support and I wish it would die.