# How to make Selenium test script works all the time?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

**Update 2**

I am working on .Net using C# with the control called GridView... so gridview control renders and spit this html something like this: this is just an one small sample html source one `TR` I have like 100s of that...

```
<tr class="item">
<td align="center">
<td align="center" style="width:15px;"/>
<td>John John</td>
<td/>
<td>Friendship</td>
<td/>
<td>
<td>9/7/2012 6:28:29 PM</td>
</tr>
```

so, I am trying to find if `John John` exists and here is how i am end-up using the XPATH

```
        int pageCount = 100;
        bool assertFlag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) 
        {
            try
            {
                string _Id = String.Format("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AddeCardControl1_gridview_control']/tbody/tr[{0}]/td[3]", i);
                string _txt = GetText(By.XPath(_Id));

                if (_txt == "some text comparing here")
                {
                    //matched
                    assertFlag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //
            }
        }
```

What do you think guys? or am I making something horrible terrible wrong?

PS: there is no ID or CSS selector I can do so I have no other options other than using the XPATH

**END UPDATE 2**

**UPDATE**

I am using Selenium WebDriver 2 with C# and I am using IE 8 and FF

**END UPDATE**

I am still not sure what causes this error to be thrown so i have script and it works and when i run the second time it fails and get the below message... and if i keep running more than once then sometimes it works and sometimes not... what should i do? what causes this error? any insight?

sometimes I get this error message:

```
Element is no longer valid
```

sometimes this:

```
Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_LeftNavigation_LeftNavigation_LeftNavigationControl1_rptLeftNav_ctl14_lnkText']
```

Comment: Can you give more info, eg what version of selenium, RC or WebDriver, are you using a Grid, which browser, and what API language?

Comment: i have updated my question, hope i answer your question, if not please let me know.

Comment: One thing you must **always** do...is be specific in XPath queries. Drop the `*` bit in the XPath query. Be very specific in what kind of control you are looking for. Also, you can make that query much simpler. You do not need to go through the entire tree. It can be something like this instead: `//table[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_AddeCardControl1_gridview_control']/descendant::tr[{0}]/td[3]`.

Comment: Arran: thanks for the tip and i will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your last question; [Getting Timeout using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217113/getting-timeout-using-selenium-webdriver) had a lot of good stuff. That was relevant to the question you're asking. If you can't find an element using one type of locator, try another type.

I also couldn't help but notice you were using an xpath locator for IE. There is a really good webinar of why you should never use xpath in IE (and in general) due to speed issues, this might be causing some of your current issues.

Here is the link: http://sauceio.com/index.php/2011/05/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath/ . The webinar investigates why CSS is superior to xpath especially with IE. CSS aside, the errors you're getting can be caused by anything though from your box settings to the browser you're using, web automation is not an exact science after all. Hell you could have a bug as well...isn't that what you're testing for in the first place?

*EDIT*

So your updates are a little strange to me because you totally switched from looking for multiple elements under something with an individual id to looking for an element in a  tag. In regard to your current update I would suggest just using the css locator saying

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td:contains('John John')"))
```

If your  tag can't be found you will doubtless be told. As I mentioned earlier, css locators accomplish the same thing as xpath, but they are faster and work better in IE. Yes they do not work 100% of the time. Maybe for 5 times out of 100 you need to use xpath over css but overall css is superior. Please read the relevant links if you are still unsure of how to utilize them, they are well written and were very helpful for me.

Comment: i dont think you can avoid xpath 100% and i try as much not to use xpath but sometimes you have no other choices but to use and for an example on my web page i have total numbers of records like this `40 total records` so if just only wants the number 40 then i have to use `xpath` because the `id` is belongs to entire line `40 total records` - hope i make sense

Comment: No you can't avoid xpath 100% but you can avoid it 95% of the time. Look into the details of how to use css, it does the same thing as xpath it's just faster. Check out [CSS Demystified](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified/) if you're unsure what I'm talking about. It has concrete examples of how you can use css to replace your xpath expressions. Also the fact that you're looking for //*[@id='foo'] is dangerous as well. This can very easily lead to StaleStateExceptions which is probably giving you trouble on this issue as well.

Comment: please have a look i have updated my question, i am still not clear on how i will be using based on my page source, i am new to Selenium so please bare with me.

Comment: Just remember `contains` is a CSS3 selector. IE8 and below are shaky at CSS3 at best.

Comment: @Arran, by shaky what do you mean? slow? because yes they are, but faster than xpath still. Or have you found they fail to locate an element when they should.

Comment: i have created a new questions since my original question bit divert so here is the question i have asked: I will accept this as an answer... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356660/unable-to-find-element-with-css-selector

Answer (score 2):

**For the First Case (Element is no longer valid):**
      When you are using a element object for long time then it will give you a error like "Element is not longer attached to DOM" This is not consistence.
Solution is you have to find the element again.
**Second (Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@id=.....):**
      Here in Xpath you have mentioned * instead of particular tag. When you have different tags with same Id in those cases it will not get which one to choose. So mention the proper tag name. You can verify the xpath using FirePath in Firefox.

Comment: From the html code what you have given, you can find specific tag in different ways. As you are saying you want the tag which contains 'John John' then why don't you go for the 'contains' method in xpath.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly speaking i don't like the type of id you mentioned in  your xPath. Try to locate needed element using css selector. And verify that you've found it properly in firepath (firebug addon).
I always avoid using IDs like  `<span id="j_idt12:j_idt13">`  cause while running seleniumt test suite from time to time they rly can be different. So better approach is to point our element directly in DOM using the whole path to element. Using this approach you avoid such inconsistences like Element "is no longer valid" or "unable to locate"